# Из .py в .exe использую pyinstaller - RecursionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Питон 3.6, использовал pyinstaller. Посмотрел в интернете, такая же ошибка возникает у тех кто использует matplotlib(не у всех).

Что сделать, чтобы программа сделалась в .exe файл? Так же пробовал 
`sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)`, не помогло.

[image: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте еще cx_Freeze
https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/

Инсталлируется
python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade

Comment: Это пробовал. Создалась папка на 250+ мб(в коде всего 240 строк) с ехе который запускался и выключался сразу.

Comment: Согласен, головной боли очень много. Поэтому я лично буду переходить на С++ под Qt. Надеюсь там уж со сборкой проблем будет меньше.